# browser.wait() for ng-if directive

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-ng-if

I have this test:

```
it('should get alert', function() {
    browser.wait(element(by.css('[ng-if="alert"]')).isPresent());

    var alert = element(by.binding('alert'));
    expect(alert.getText()).toBe('Copy clicked!');
});
```

for this html:

```
<div ng-if="alert" class="ng-scope">
    <br>
    <b layout="row" layout-align="center center" class="md-padding">
      {{alert}}
    </b>
</div>
```

The browser is not waiting for the alert block to be present so the test is failing.  If I use `browser.sleep()` to wait for it then it works but I don't want to use `browser.sleep()`.  I have tried using `browser.wait()` with xpath, css path, className, and the css you see in the question.  None of these have worked.  Is it even possible to tell the browser to wait for an ng-if block?

SOLUTION:

```
it('should get alert', function() {
    browser.wait(function() {
        return element(by.css('[ng-if="alert"]')).isPresent();
    ), 10000};

    var alert = element(by.binding('alert'));
    expect(alert.getText()).toBe('Copy clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to return a promise that resolves to a boolean:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  var waitTimeInMilliseconds = 10000;
  return element(by.css('[ng-if="alert"]')).isPresent()
}, waitTimeInMilliseconds);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm getting an error that the wait is timing out after about 40ms. Is there a way to tell it a maximum or minimum wait time?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Just had to put ", 10000" at the end. Thanks for the help :)
Updated it in my question as well